# Can not connect to Postgres Container from pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, docker

related posts:
1) [docker postgres pgadmin local connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540711/docker-postgres-pgadmin-local-connection)

2) https://coderwall.com/p/qsr3yq/postgresql-with-docker-on-os-x (in the example "Name" entry is not filled in)

there are two ways to complete this task, I use official postgres

METHOD 1:

and runs it with

```
sudo docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -p 5432:5432 -d postgres
```

then connect with

```
Name: postgres
Host: localhost
Port: 5432
user
pass
...
```

METHOD 2:

starts with

```
sudo docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres
```

and then check the ip of container

```
sudo docker inspect
```

say result

```
172.17.42.1
```

then connect with pgAdmin tab Properties filled info

```
Name: postgres
Host: 172.17.42.1
Port: 5432
user
pass
...
```

Comment: and error itself?.. tried to psql first?..

Comment: Since you've mapped port 5432 of container to that of host, can't you use pgadmin to connect to port 5432 on the host? What error do you get when you try to connect?

Comment: thanks for the comment. Problem solved by my self, since I have forward the port in Container to local port , I should use localhost or 127.0.0.1 as host address to connect to. I would reedit the question into a guide

Comment: @Hellolad Adding an answer based on my comment so that it can help if someone else stumbles upon this in future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're mapping the port 5432 on the container to the same port on host with `-p 5432:5432` in your `docker run` statement, try connecting pgadmin to port 5432 on the host instead of the container.

Comment: Oh if only it was that simple. It won't take `127.0.0.1` nor `localhost` and of course the port is set to 5432 in the Create - Server dialog [in pgadmin]. I will admit that I do NOT grok the difference between the Container and Host if the port numbers are the same, and I'm specifying the host (/ my machine) in the `Host name/address` field.

Answer (score 10):

I included this in the docker yaml file to get the database and pgAdmin:

```
database:
    image: postgres:10.4-alpine
    container_name: kafka-nodejs-example-database
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    expose:
      - "5432"
    ports:
      - 8000:5432
    volumes:
      - ./services/database/schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-schema.sql
      - ./services/database/seed.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2-seed.sql
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
      - 5454:5454/tcp
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@mydomain.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=postgres
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=5454
```

The postgres username is alphaone and the password is xxxxxxxxxxx.

Do a `docker ps` to get the container id and then `docker inspect <dockerContainerId> | grep IPAddress`

eg: `docker inspect 2f50fabe8a87 | grep IPAddress`

Insert the Ip address into pgAdmin and the database credentials used in docker:

[image: pgAdmin]

Comment: I followed the steps but this is connecting to my local postgres server. Not the docker database.