# Using PGAdmin Extension in Docker Desktop for PostgreSQL Image: can't connect

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin

Question seems identical to [Can not connect to Postgres Container from pgAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798160/can-not-connect-to-postgres-container-from-pgadmin) but none of those solutions seem to be working, and I'm using slightly different tools... so maybe different problem?

In my Docker Desktop (running Windows with a Linux Docker), standard install, I've installed the postgres:latest image and created a container from it. I used the following settings:

[image: Screen Shot: PG Docker Image install]

The log in the container shows success:

```
2023-05-28 14:56:30 2023-05-28 18:56:30.313 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.3 (Debian 15.3-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2023-05-28 14:56:30 2023-05-28 18:56:30.313 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-05-28 14:56:30 2023-05-28 18:56:30.313 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-05-28 14:56:30 2023-05-28 18:56:30.319 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-05-28 14:56:30 2023-05-28 18:56:30.325 UTC [62] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-05-28 18:56:30 UTC
2023-05-28 14:56:30 2023-05-28 18:56:30.329 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

On the terminal tab, I'm able to connect to the local instance:

```
# psql -p 5432 -U postgres
psql (15.3 (Debian 15.3-1.pgdg110+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \l
                                                List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    | ICU Locale | Locale Provider |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            |            |                 | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            |            |                 | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)

postgres=#
```

I did a `docker inspect pgserver` and saw the network settings as such:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "7752ebc73909a6a14039b287472724b48fb8138d4466a41eb368fd91057dbcbc",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "5432/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "54320"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/7752ebc73909",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "a00a861f13fb77a019123b42affeed42f11a8cac8ab00f609b6b2cbfc76e4ee6",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "a28aecb0b5fd55718069e079194fcf39c84a380041a82f0ec6de8f7b3565dd6a",
                    "EndpointID": "a00a861f13fb77a019123b42affeed42f11a8cac8ab00f609b6b2cbfc76e4ee6",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
```

I have also installed the PGAdmin4 Docker Desktop extension, but I cannot configure it to connect to my postgres instance.

- I have tried to connect to 127.0.0.1 on ports 5432 and 54320.
- I have tried to connect to 172.17.0.3 on the same ports.
- I have tried to connect to pgserver on the same ports.
- I have tried to connect to localhost on the same ports.
- I have ensured that SSL Mode is set to "prefer".

Depending on what I use, I get an error message that the connection is refused, or a connection timeout error.

What am I doing wrong?

Per request in comments, results of `docker ps` are below.

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                     NAMES
0ed9f3f293fd   postgres:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   20 hours ago   Up 20 hours   0.0.0.0:54320->5432/tcp   pgserver
```

Comment: can you provide the screenshot for  the following command docker ps

Comment: @Balint I've added the data you asked for.

Answer (score 5):

Docker is not able to resolve the hostname as PgAdmin extension is also running in a separate container.

Use `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in PgAdmin connection properties to access the PostgreSQL server.

[PgAdmin Database Connection Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZu5u.png)

Comment: This is the answer

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that the problem is not docker or the port configuration
But the configuration of postgress in particular what connection are allowed defined in the

```
/var/lib/pgsql/12/data/pg_hba.conf
```

you may need to configure it like

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
```

you need to do this in way the is persistent via volumes

Comment: I added this line and restarted the image (path was a bit different, but not hard to figure out) but I am not seeing any difference in behavior.

Comment: will try to replicate on my machine I will be in touch