# Cannot connect to Postgres running in Docker from PGAdmin running on Windows Host

Tags: postgresql, docker, virtualbox

I have read all the questions on this, [like this one,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540711/docker-postgres-pgadmin-local-connection?rq=1) but it does not help.

Host: Windows 10, running VirtualBox and PgAdmin.

I have setup Docker correctly and run a few containers without issue. Now I tried to setup Postgres. I tried two:

1 https://hub.docker.com/r/paintedfox/postgresql/

2 https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

And both have the same issue. When I try to connect from PgAdmin, it says the server does not listen.

When I run `docker inspect postgres` I see

> "NetworkSettings": {
>               "Bridge": "",
>               "SandboxID": "6ad76f4d61017c44f814c5ec7ab9081a650d925a46c2b69902c4f0e5209076ce",
>               "HairpinMode": false,
>               "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
>               "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
>               "Ports": {
>                   "5432/tcp": null
>               },
>               "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/6ad76f4d6101",
>               "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
>               "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
>               "EndpointID": "3f14630554c972ac875cbb384725c6970d1d4d5acfba7cbc05e416b5b22f0056",
>               "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
>               "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
>               "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
>               "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",

I have tried that IP address as the host in PGAdmin.

I have tried setting the container with -p 5432:5432 and connecting as 127.0.0.1:5432.

I have tried setting port forwarding in VirtualBox for the container.

I also tried the machine host, as shown in Kitematic: 192.168.99.100

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally noticed that in Kitematc in the IP & Ports section on the Home tab that the ACCESS URL was not set.

Under Docker Port it shows '5432/tcp'

So I clicked the IP address next to that and set it and now it shows:

192.168.99.100:32768

I put that IP and port into PGAdmin and it can now connect to the container.

FYI that IP is the same IP returned by:

```
docker-machine ip default
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run your container from command-line alter your run-command like this:

```
docker run -p 32768:5432 my-postgres
```

Now you can connect to your postgres via `<mapped-ip>:32768` (in my case the mapped IP was 192.168.99.100)