# Connecting pgadmin to postgres in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, nginx, docker-compose, pgadmin

I have a `docker-compose` file with services for `python`, `nginx`, `postgres` and `pgadmin`:

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5431:5431"

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    links:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: pwdpwd
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./foobar  # This refs a Dockerfile with Python and Django requirements
    command: ["/wait-for-it.sh", "postgres:5431", "--", "/gunicorn.sh"]
    volumes:
      - staticfiles_root:/foobar/static
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./foobar/docker/nginx
    volumes:
      - staticfiles_root:/foobar/static
    depends_on:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:80"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  staticfiles_root:
  pgadmin:
```

When I run `docker-compose up` and visit `localhost:5050`, I see the `pgadmin` interface. When I try to create a new server there, with `localhost` or `0.0.0.0` as host name and `5431` as port, I get an error "Could not connect to server". If I remove these and instead enter `postgres` in the "Service" field, I get the error "definition of service "postgres" not found". How can I connect to the database with `pgadmin`?

Comment: Be careful that the default postgres port is 5432 not 5431. You should update the port mapping for the postgres service in your compose file. The wrong port might be the reason for the issues you reported. Change the port mapping and then try to connect to postgres:5432. localhost:5432 will not work.

Comment: @CiprianStoica That worked, thanks! If you add it as an answer I'll mark it right.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I just added it as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be careful that the default postgres port is 5432 not 5431. You should update the port mapping for the postgres service in your compose file. The wrong port might be the reason for the issues you reported. Change the port mapping and then try to connect to postgres:5432. localhost:5432 will not work.

Answer (score 7):

the docker container name changes when you run docker-compose to prefix the folder name (to keep container names unique). You could force the name of the container with `container_name` property

```
version: "3"
services:

  # postgres database
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12.3
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=admin
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust # allow all connections without a password. This is *not* recommended for prod
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ # persist data even if container shuts down
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  # pgadmin for managing postgis db (runs at localhost:5050)
  # To add the above postgres server to pgadmin, use hostname as defined by docker: 'postgres'
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=5050
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
  
volumes:
  database-data:
```

Another option is to connect the postgres container to localhost with

`network_mode: host`

But you lose the nice network isolation from docker that way