# Docker - Postgres and pgAdmin 4 : Connection refused

Tags: postgresql, docker

Newbie with docker, I am trying to connect throught localhost my pgAdmin container to the postgres one.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                         NAMES
0b00555238ba        dpage/pgadmin4      "/entrypoint.sh"         43 minutes ago      Up 43 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 443/tcp   pedantic_turing
e79fb6440a95        postgres            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp        pg-docker
```

I succeed connecting with psql command.

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres -d postgres
```

But when I create the server on pgAdmin with the same parameters as psql I got the following error.

> Unable to connect to server:
>
> could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running
>   on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on
>   port 5432? could not connect to server: Address not available Is the
>   server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections on port 5432?

I succeed to connect throught the IPAddress given by `docker inspect` on the container.

By the way, I checked postgresql.conf and assert that `listen_addresses = '*'` and also that pg_hba.conf contain `host all all all md5`.

But I don't get it, why shouldn't I be able to use the localhost address ? And why does docker even give me an address that is not local ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does localhost means inside a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278632/what-does-localhost-means-inside-a-docker-container)

Comment: I answered this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540711/docker-postgres-pgadmin-local-connection/57729412#57729412

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In this case:

1. Pgadmin fails to connect to localhost, but psql works from outside docker.
2. both pgadmin & Postgres are running as Containers

Although you haven't indicated if you are doing so, ideally both containers could be part of a custom [bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) for automatic DNS resolution.

If not added explicitly they will be part of the default bridge network.

To find out the networks created in your docker runtime, type:
$ `docker network ls`

Some networks will be listed in the console, maybe you'll find a `[name]_default` it should be your network.

Execute 
`docker network inspect [name]_default` 
it'll show up a bunch of information, for us the most important is IPv4Address, something like this:
`"7c3cd7532ab8aacc70830afb74adad7296d9c8ddd725c498af2d7ee2d2c2aadd": {
                "Name": "intime_postegres_1",
                "EndpointID": "56a9cb574469f22259497b72719f9f4a3e555b09f95058fcf389ef5287381f28",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }`

Instead of using localhost for the server name/ip in the pgAdmin new server dialog, connect to the postgres instance's "IPv4Address".

In my case connecting at `172.18.0.2:5432`, worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks it works but isn't foolproof as a restart would change the ip.

Comment: Yes, it´s true I haven't figure it out, but maybe has a good solution for that. I only used on dev environment. Do u have any clue?

Comment: Using the `name` instead of the ip works even when you restart.

Comment: The solution work for locally or same domain/intranet only. It doesn't work for public ips

Answer (score 33):

I too had the case when you're able to connect with `psql` command on terminal but not with pgAdmin4.
The following solution worked for me.

First -

```
docker ps
```

From there you'll get the container name/ID of the postgres container, then do -

```
docker inspect name_of_container_here
```

It'll give you something like this -

```
 "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "f35dbe66b36cd38673aad6e1278ad33031ef9d5abd34582d4b91955e288f855e",
                    "EndpointID": "2e63ea59e9d0de7526bb02ba29bc0b16bcad51b8963127ad380416d15da994db",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
```

Note the IPAddress and provide that while creating a new server in pgAdmin4 - 
[image]

Comment: Create new server for Docker to access Postgres really helps me, thank you!

Comment: Same, 172.17.0.2 worked for me. But it is troubling that localhost does not... why is this the case? Launching pgadmin in Docker, localhost in my browser brings up pgadmin...

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue and I solved it in a non-canonical way, but very satisfactory to my local workflow.

I always start my postgresql container with a `docker-compose.yaml` file. So I just added the pgAdmin to the same compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  my_awesome_db:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    container_name: postgresql-local
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/postgres.sock:/var/run/postgres/postgres.sock"
      - "/home/myuser/docker-apps/volumes/postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
  pg_admin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    container_name: pgadmin4
    ports:
      - "15432:80"
    environment:
      - GUNICORN_THREADS=1
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=my_awesome_email@email.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=does_not_matter
    depends_on:
      - my_awesome_db
```

So I access pgAdmin on my localhost:15432 (just because it's easy to remember), and I've configured pgAdmin with:

```
Host: my_awesome_db
Port: 5432
Username: postgres
```

Comment: I think "localhost:5050" is easy to remember but aside from that, your solution worked for me. I'm using Docker for Windows btw. Thanks!

Comment: The key point here is to use container service name (`my_awesome_db`, `pg_admin`) as a host name when connecting through pgAdmin. From official docs [Networking in compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/): `By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.`

Answer (score 7):

For me worked like this:

Add Server -> Connection -> Hostname/address

Set field to 172.17.0.1

More info at Docker Network doc: https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone

Answer (score 4):

first you need to get container information

```
$docker ps
```

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                         NAMES
0b00555238ba        dpage/pgadmin4      "/entrypoint.sh"         43 minutes ago      Up 43 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 443/tcp   pedantic_turing
e79fb6440a95        postgres            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp        pg-docker
```

then extract IP Address

```
$sudo docker inspect e79fb6440a95 | grep IPAddress
```

```
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPAddress": "192.168.64.2",
```

And when you create your server put your IP Address

[image]

Comment: The `docker inspect` IP address isn't stable; if the container is deleted or recreated it's possible for that address to change.  You shouldn't ever need to look it up.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify in your connection string the, server parameter, the name of your container name and not the localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot, or code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Because I was connecting to a server on the host, it was as simple as adding

`--net host`

to the docker run command, so that the container gets access to the host's ports.

Answer (score 0):

My pgAdmin runs on the docker host (osx). In **docker-compose.yml** I had to set

```
ports:
  - 5432:5432
```

explicit. This line was not there before. But this oneliner did the trick.

Here's my example:

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mysecret
      POSTGRES_USER: myuser
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    ...
    ...
```

**After that, I can connect to "localhost" with pgadmin. And it is save if you restart your container! You don't need to search for the ipaddress with docker inspect**

If you don't do this, your docker will not have a HostIp "0.0.0.0" but only a tcp 5432 connection.

Background information:

1. Check your running docker container `docker ps`
2. Get the name of your pgsql and do `docker inspect name_of_container_here`
3. Find the row "Ports:

Before change the docker-compose.yml the `docker-inspect ...` will show the "Ports" 5432/tcp is null:

```
...
"Ports": {
    "5432/tcp": null
},
...
```

After changing the docker-compose.yml, `docker inspect ...` will show you the following, where you now can see "HostIp": "0.0.0.0", aso ...

```
...
"Ports": {
    "5432/tcp": [
        {
           "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
           "HostPort": "5432"
        }
    ]
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I connecting in pgadmin 4 by setting Host as localhost!

[image: PgAdmin connection properties]

docker-compose.yml:

```
timesheets.db:
  image: postgres:latest
  container_name: timesheets.db
  environment: 
    - POSTGRES_DB=timesheets
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  volumes:
    - ./.containers/timesheets-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  hostname: timesheets.db
  ports:
    - 5432:5432
```

Answer (score -1):

it worked for me too, I used localhost as hostname

Comment: This response is more appropriate as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).