# Problem with postgresql and pgadmin docker containers

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to connect `postgresql` and `pgadmin4` work together.
`pgadmin4` works fine but when I try to create a new server I have 2 problems:

- if the `postgres` container is at other port that is not 5432 it dont recognize that port. It show this error: `could not connect to server: Connection refused
  Is the server running on host "172.17.0.5" and accepting
  TCP/IP connections on port 5431?`
- if the `postgres` container is at port 5432 the error is `FATAL: password authentication failed for user "example"`.

I execute this command to get `postgres` container:  `docker run -p 5431:5432 --name postgres2 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ad1234 -d postgres`.

I try, following other responses in stackoverflow, adding this command `-c"listen_addresses='*'"` and I enter in the config file too but noone of this work to me.

Hope you can help me, thanks.

### EDIT [Solved]

Ok I solved, it was a big fail by my part. I was using `172.17.0.5` (the IP container address) and what I need to use to connect is `172.17.01` (the Gateway). 
Thanks for you time.

Comment: `Is the server running on host "172.17.0.5" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5431?` - well, is it? How have you tried to test that the IP and port are correct?

Comment: that IP is the postgres container IP, and port I think is correct because I redirect it when I ran it the first time `-p 5431:5432`. I execute the comand `docker inspect postgres2` and in the section of `network` i got this `"IPAddress": "172.17.0.5",` and in the section of `ports` got this `"Ports": {
                "5432/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "5431"
                    }
                ]
`

Comment: So, according to what you have just posted, it is not listening on 172.17.0.5;5432 is it

Comment: when I do `docker start -a postgres2` this is what I get `2019-04-30 22:26:32.062 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2019-04-30 22:26:32.062 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2019-04-30 22:26:32.073 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2019-04-30 22:26:32.122 UTC [24] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-04-30 22:24:12 UTC
2019-04-30 22:26:32.128 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
`

Comment: I answered this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540711/docker-postgres-pgadmin-local-connection/57729412#57729412

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduce your scenario this way:

```
# docker run -p 5431:5432 --name postgres2 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ad1234 -d postgres
# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
d4030c577a24        postgres            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago      Up 2 minutes       0.0.0.0:5431->5432/tcp   postgres2

# sudo -u postgres psql -h localhost -p 5431
could not change directory to "/root": Permission denied
Password: 
psql (10.5, server 11.2 (Debian 11.2-1.pgdg90+1))
WARNING: psql major version 10, server major version 11.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE DATABASE mytestdb;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# \q
```

Now starting docker for pgadmin and being able to connect to postgresql:

```
docker run -p 80:80 --link postgres2 -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=user@domain.com" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=SuperSecret" -d dpage/pgadmin4
```

With the above command you can link the postgres2 docker to the pgadmin docker and then on creating a connection on pgadmin4 you should use:

- host name/address: postgres2
- port: 5432
- Maintenance database: postgres
- username: postgres

with that, I've connected to Postgres from pgadmin4

As far as I know, docker PostgreSQL comes by default with localhost only connection and if you want to add remote connection you should add "listen_addresses = '*'" to postgresql.conf

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean with your comment sorry.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question, adding data regarding the pgadmin connection

Comment: This works too. I accept this like a valid response. I think this works because you use `--link` because I did it without that command and mine didnt work. I tested like you did and it works perfectly.