# PostgreSQL and pgAdmin both running in Docker containers and connecting

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin

I am attempting to run both PostgreSQL and pgAdmin in Docker containers. The idea is that the PostgreSQL database should be accessible to any applications I have running on the host machine, and also to pgAdmin.

I am using this command to run PostgreSQL:

```
docker run -d -e POSTGRES_USER=username -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password --name postgres -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

And to run [pgAdmin](https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4):

```
docker run -d -p 1111:1111 --name pgadmin -e "PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=1111" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@test.com" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=test" dpage/pgadmin4
```

If I go to `localhost:1111`, I can connect to pgAdmin and login. However, when I try to connect to my local PostgreSQL instance, it gets no response.

Therefore, I tried to run pgAdmin with access to the host internet using `--net=host` instead of `-p 1111:1111`:

```
docker run -d --net=host --name pgadmin -e "PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=1111" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@test.com" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=test" dpage/pgadmin4
```

Now, when I try to go to `localhost:1111` to connect to pgAdmin, I get no response in my browser.

Docker Compose is a possible solution, as I could link the two containers together so they could access each other without having to worry about ports, but I also need pgAdmin to be able to access PostgreSQL instances on other machines, as well as my local one.

I feel like `--net=host` is broken in Docker. There's a whole thread [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/should-docker-run-net-host-work/14215) with a lot of confusion.

My setup:

```
Host: Windows 10
Docker: Docker Desktop Community v2.0.0.3 (31259)
```

#### Update

I have now tried using `--link postgres` on the pgAdmin container and it allows me to connect to my local instance of PostgreSQL but not non-local ones, the full command is:

```
docker run -d -p 1111:1111 --link postgres --name pgadmin -e "PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=1111" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@test.com" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=test" dpage/pgadmin4
```

Comment: I have the "same" problem last week https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55928586/problem-with-postgresql-and-pgadmin-docker-containers , Hope this help you.

Comment: @Schwarz54 The accepted answer on your post is a little bit useful, I have now found that using `--link postgres` will at least let pgAdmin access just my local instance of PostgreSQL but I also need it to be able to access any non-local ones too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands were not wrong, only the connection in pgAdmin, so the full list of commands are:

---

For PostgreSQL:

```
docker run -d -e POSTGRES_USER=username -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password --name postgres -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

And pgAdmin:

```
docker run -d -p 1111:1111 --name pgadmin -e "PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=1111" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@test.com" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=test" dpage/pgadmin4
```

---

Now the `pgAdmin` container won't connect to `localhost` but needs the IP of the PostgreSQL container. Run:

```
docker inspect postgres
```

Inspect result:

```
[
    {
        ...
        "NetworkSettings": {
            ...
            "Networks": {
                ...
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
                ...
            }
        }
    }
]
```

We're only interested in the `IPAddress` from the `inspect` command. This is the IP which pgAdmin should connect to.

pgAdmin is also capable of access external IPs from your machine.

Comment: But the ips would change when we restart the container correct? How do we refer to the container in a more persistent manner?

Comment: @hakish I'd recommend using Docker Compose. Containers in the same yaml file can connect to each other using the name of the container (such as `postgres:5432`). I have a blogpost which is half finished you might want to look at: https://github.com/Harvzor/portfolio/blob/docker-blogpost/data/blog/docker.md#adding-pgadmin

Answer (score 0):

When you create docker containers it creates a bridge network. First find the network range for the bridge network. You can use `ifconfig` to find it.  Let's say 172.17.0.5 is ip of pgAdmin, Then create a user 'root'@'172.17.0.5' for PostgreSQL and give database permissions for that user. Then you can connect to the database. Also check if port 3306 is accessible using telnet.