# Docker LAMP stack - where is the location to keep PHP projects?

Tags: php, apache, docker, dockerfile, lamp

I have my LAMP stack installed already before Docker's. And I am using this image to build and run my Docker's LAMP stack:

```
$ docker pull linuxconfig/lamp
```

After all are downloaded and installed:

```
$ docker run -it linuxconfig/lamp /bin/bash
root@2e80dfd55a6e:/# service apache2 start
[....] Starting web server: apache2AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

So at my http://172.17.0.2/, I can see this **default** page:

[image]

But where can I locate its location so that I can put my PHP projects in there?

This the DockerFile from that image:

```
FROM linuxconfig/apache
MAINTAINER Lubos Rendek <web@linuxconfig.org>

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# Main package installation
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install supervisor libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql mysql-server

# Extra package installation
RUN apt-get -y install php5-gd php-apc php5-mcrypt

# Configure MySQL
RUN sed -i 's/bind-address/#bind-address/' /etc/mysql/my.cnf

# Include supervisor configuration
ADD supervisor-lamp.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
ADD supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/

# Include PHP Info page
ADD index.php /var/www/html/index.php

# Create new MySQL admin user
RUN service mysql start; mysql -u root -e "CREATE USER 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';";mysql -u root -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;"; 

# Allow ports
EXPOSE 80 3306

# Start supervisor
CMD ["supervisord"]
```

EDIT:

```
$ sudo docker run --name=lamp -dP -v $PWD/html:/var/www/html linuxconfig/lamp
c2d1687aef21f8a12a7fbb31bf8cf71c1e5adabf381bc6d70e8804c6663f0bc0
```

And:

```
$ sudo docker port lamp
80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32769
3306/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32768
```

I go to my browser at: http://172.17.0.2:32769/

I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this article can help: "[LAMP ( Linux, Apache, MariaDB, PHP ) stack Docker image deployment](https://linuxconfig.org/lamp-linux-apache-mariadb-php-stack-docker-image-deployment)"

Save `index.php` file and within a new `html` directory.
Alternatively, `html` directory may contain your desired PHP application:

```
$ mkdir html
$ vi html/index.php
$ ls html/
index.php
```

> At this stage we are ready to deploy “`linuxconfig/lamp`” docker image:

```
sudo docker run --name=lamp -dP -v $PWD/html:/var/www/html linuxconfig/lamp
```

That means you are mounting your host directory `html` into the `linuxconfig/lamp` container folder `/var/www/html`. (see "[Mount a host directory as a data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume)")

Comment: thanks for the answer. I now get an error of `This site can’t be reached

172.17.0.2 refused to connect.` . please see my edit above. thanks.

Comment: @teelou what is your OS? Windows? Linux? Mac? What docker are you using? a toolbox one based on VirtualBox? Or HyperV (Docker for WindowsX)? Or based on the XHyve  VM? (Docker for Mac)

Comment: I'm on Linux Xubuntu 16.04.

Comment: my docker - `$ docker --version
Docker version 1.12.5, build 7392c3b`

Comment: No VirtualBox is installed.

Comment: @teelou Normal: on Linux, you don't need a VM to run Linux(!). Why do you access http://172.17.0.2:32769/? Why port 32769? Why not directly http://172.17.0.2?

Comment: bcos it gives me `80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32769` so I tot that is the address.

Comment: @teelou did you try at port 80? I mean, in your question, when you see a page, you were visiting at port 80.

Comment: @teelou strange, considering the `/var/www/html/index.html` mounted as a volume should reflect your own `index.html` file, not the default one.

Comment: I have standard LAMP stack installed already at port 80. So I get the list of my standard LAMP stack projects that I keep there at http://127.0.0.1/

Comment: @teelou OK, I did not know that. So: regarding your container, can you try visiting at http://localhost:32769? And make sure your container is still running, with a docker ps.

Comment: aww yes I can see my project/ page at http://localhost:32769/ now. but not with the IP address. how come?

Comment: @teelou You might have to ignore the 172.17.0.2 ip: it seems to be a generic message, also seen in http://stackoverflow.com/q/35165370/6309. localhost should be enough.

Comment: @teelou as seen here https://forums.docker.com/t/unable-to-access-docker-exposed-port-on-windows-machine/5865/4, 172.17.0.2 must be the IP of your container (which is Apache reports when it starts from said container), but from your host, you should use localhost only.

Comment: Thank you. 172.17.0.2 is generated by docker when I run this line `$ docker run -it linuxconfig/lamp /bin/bash` (check it out in my question above).