# Can't save file on remote Jupyter server running in docker container

Tags: docker, ssh, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to work in Jupyter Lab run via Docker on a remote machine, but can't save any of the files I open.

I'm working with a [Jupyter Docker Stack](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/selecting.html#jupyter-tensorflow-notebook). I've installed docker on my remote machine and successfully pulled the image.

I set up port forwarding in my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```bash
Host mytunnel
  HostName <remote ip>
  User root
  ForwardAgent yes
  LocalForward 8888 localhost:8888
```

When I fire up the container, I use the following script:

```
docker run \
  -p 8888:8888 \
  -e JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes \
  -v "${PWD}":/home/jovyan/work jupyter/tensorflow-notebook
```

The container is running:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
c8fc3c720af1   jupyter/tensorflow-notebook   "tini -g -- start-no…"   8 minutes ago   Up 8 minutes   0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp, :::8888->8888/tcp   adoring_khorana
```

I get the regular Jupyter url back:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=<token>
```

But when I access the server in my browser, the Save option is disabled.

[image]

I've tried some of the solutions proposed [elsewhere in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576193/create-ssh-tunnel-to-remote-docker-container-running-jupyter-notebook), but no luck.

Is this something about connecting over SSH? The Jupyter server thinks it's not a secure connection?

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/cant-save-file-when-working-on-remote-container/15172?u=fomightez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the problem is related to the SSH configuration, but I think is more probably related to a permission issue with your volume mount.

Please, try reviewing your docker container logs looking for permissions related errors. You can do that using the [following](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_logs/):

```
docker container logs <container id>
```

See the output provided by your `docker run` command too.

In addition, try opening a shell in the container:

```
docker exec -it <container id> /bin/bash
```

and see if you are able to create a file in the default work directory:

```
touch /home/jovyan/work/test_file
```

Finally, the Jupyter docker stacks repository has a [troubleshooting page](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/main/docs/using/troubleshooting.md) almost entirely devoted to permissions issues.

Consider especially the solutions provided in the [Additional tips and troubleshooting commands for permission-related errors](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/main/docs/using/troubleshooting.md#additional-tips-and-troubleshooting-commands-for-permission-related-errors) and, as suggested, try providing launching the container with your OS user:

```
docker run \
  -p 8888:8888 \
  -e JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes \
  --user "$(id -u)" --group-add users \
  -v "${PWD}":/home/jovyan/work jupyter/tensorflow-notebook
```

After that, as suggested in the mentioned documentation as well, see if the container is properly mounted using the following command:

```
docker inspect <container_id>
```

In the obtained result note the value of the `RW` field which indicates whether the volume is writable (`true`) or not (`false`).

Comment: This was exactly the problem: A permissions issue. The docker script you gave was exactly what I needed. Many thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. That is great @ncgoodbody. I am very happy to hear that the answer was helpful and that you were able to solve your problem.