# How to get IP address of running docker container

Tags: docker, containers, docker-for-mac

I am using Docker for Mac. I am running a nodejs based microservice in a Docker container. I want to test node microservice through the browser. How to get IP address of running docker container?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a Docker container's IP address from the host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157721/how-to-get-a-docker-containers-ip-address-from-the-host)

Answer (score 157):

If you don't want to map ports from your host to the container you can access directly to the docker range ip for the container. This range is by default only accessed from your host. You can check your container network data doing:

```
docker inspect <containerNameOrId>
```

Probably is better to filter:

```
docker inspect <containerNameOrId> | grep '"IPAddress"' | head -n 1
```

Usually, the default docker ip range is `172.17.0.0/16`. Your host should be `172.17.0.1` and your first container should be `172.17.0.2` if everything is normal and you didn't specify any special network options.

**EDIT**
Another more elegant way using docker features instead of "bash tricking":

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" <containerNameOrId>
```

**EDIT2**
For modern docker engines, now it is this way (thanks to the commenters!):

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <containerNameOrId>
```

Comment: You are talking about the internal IP, and it has nothing to do with the question at hand. Your answer provide just confusion to the reader. Since the IP is the IP of the machine where the Docker is running on. Which is just `localhost` :)

Comment: You are wrong. The OP didn't specify anything about the microservice must be accesible from outside. He only said "test node microservice through the browser" and this can be done with my proposed method using `http://172.17.0.2:anyPort` from the host. Of course if you want to access it using localhost on host, you must map ports. Will see what the OP wants.

Comment: You are saying that you can access the internal IP inside the Container from the host? That is physical impossible, that is a completely a different network. Not only I just checked and yes, I can't access the 172.17.0.7 of my docker container, then I should be able to see all the docker contender if I scan my host machine with a network scanner, and this is not the case again. I know that it should not work, I tested what you say (you never know) and it is not working. So maybe your explanation is missing a key part?

Comment: The containers are accessible from the host. Try it yourself... I'll give you some hints. 1. Download an run container: `docker run --name struts --rm -i tomcat` 2. Get your container's ip (if you have only one): `docker inspect struts | grep '"IPAddress"' | head -n 1` 3. Open it on host's browser `http://x.x.x.x:8080` . You can see Apache Tomcat default's page.

Comment: Exactly how I say it and how the documentation says it of Tomcat on https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/: `http://localhost:8888 or http://host-ip:8888`. Because this is how the Tomcat Docker is configured, and is configured to pass 8080 to port 8888. I recommend reading - https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/ and building some container yourself to understand how it all works. You can't access the docker form the internal IP. It is an impossibility. That is not how network works.

Comment: I know about `-p` use. How do you explain this example I put is working without using `-p` on docker run? It's accesible from host. Is tomcat container special for some reason?

Comment: I investigated further and you are wrong David. default iptables rules for docker unless you specify something different make containers accessible only from host by default. The `-p`option is to map ports to your host but what I proposed is to access directly to container's ip which is 100% correct too.

Comment: I wasn't able to access the web app in the container without mapping port using -p

Comment: The command should be docker inspect <containerNameOrId> | grep '"IPAddress"' | tail -n 1

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis - I don't know anything about this, but https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/ says "By default, when you create a container, it does not publish any of its ports to the outside world. To make a port available to services outside of Docker, or to Docker containers which are not connected to the container’s network, use the --publish or -p flag."  If that is true, then the setup for tomcat must be doing something beyond the default Docker config. What reference did you find that describes "default iptables rules for docker"?

Comment: You can check the iptables rules... to access to a container from the host is not accesing "from outside world" and it can be done as default.

Comment: The format option is outdated and no longer works with newer docker engines, check answer by Nima Ghoroubi.

Comment: While the latest edit works, it, sadly, only shows the IPv4 address of the container, not its IPv6.

Answer (score 28):

Use `--format` option to get only the IP address instead whole container info:

```
sudo docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' <CONTAINER ID>
```

Comment: In windows host use double quotes instead of single quote. 
E.g.  sudo docker inspect --format "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" <CONTAINER ID or NAME>
Reference: [link](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/433)

Comment: new format of info about container [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/#get-an-instances-ip-address)

Answer (score 24):

For modern docker engines use this command :

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id
```

and for older engines use :

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' container_name_or_id
```

Comment: As mentioned and linked in the comment by @sanyash up in the original OP area.

Comment: Template parsing error: template: :1: unexpected unclosed action in command

Answer (score 10):

if you want to obtain it right within the container, you can try

```
ip a | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" | grep 172.17
```

Answer (score 6):

You can start your container with the flag `-P`. This "assigns" a random port to the exposed port of your image.

With `docker port <container id>` you can see the randomly choosen port. Access is then possible via `localhost:port`.

Answer (score 2):

For my case, below worked **on Mac**:

I could not access container IPs directly on Mac. I need to use `localhost` with port forwarding, e.g. if the port is 8000, then `http://localhost:8000`

See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds

The original answer was from: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2670#issuecomment-371249949

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view the IP address from within the running container, `/etc/hosts` file is a great place to look at. Now, to uniquely identify the entry within the `hosts` file, it is a good practise to run the container with the `-h` option. Sample commands are given below:

1. Run the container with `-h` set:

`docker run -td -h guju <image name>`

2. Log in to the running container and view the `/etc/hosts` file. It will show an entry like this:

`172.17.0.5 guju`

Answer (score -1):

this will list all containers' IP addresses

```
while read ctr;do
    sudo docker inspect --format "$ctr "'{{.Name}}{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' $ctr
done < <(docker ps -a --filter status=running --format '{{.ID}}')
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score -4):

You can not access the docker's IP from outside of that host machine.
If your browser is on another machine better to map the host port to container port by passing `-p 8080:8080` to run command.

Passing `-p` you can map host port to container port and a proxy is set to forward all traffix for said host port to designated container port.