# How to access the Docker shiny application?

Tags: docker

My question is quite simple and intuitive but I cannot get it resolved for weeks.

I'm using Docker on windows 8. (Of course it's **Docker toolbox**+**VirtualBox**).
And I pushed image to Docker Hub and using **Kitematic** to deploy R shiny app.

[image]

The pic above shows it's running  but I cannot access it through the given Docker machine IP *192.168.99.100:32772*

I also used `docker inspect` to get the container IP(*172.17.0.3*) but did not work neither. 
[image]
[image]

I've also already consulted other related posts on stackoverflow, thanks for any advice in advance.

[How to get into a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172605/how-to-get-into-a-docker-container)

[How to get IP address of running docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43692961/how-to-get-ip-address-of-running-docker-container)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to execute the docker image keeping your proxy server checkbox uncheck.

*Path -> Chrome Browser -> Right Top Corner (3 dots ) -> Settings -> Open Proxy Settings -> Connections Tab -> LAN Settings -> Proxy Server -> Uncheck the proxy*

Launch the docker console ( or cmd) and do docker run to execute your docker image

Comment: I can visit the shiny app at 192.168.00.100:3838 on the host. But I cannot visit it from a remote machine (my notebook).