# In VSTS, async Jest tests that connect to dockerized ArangoDB database time out

Tags: azure-devops, jestjs, azure-pipelines, arangodb

I'm trying to run jest tests with a Visual Studio Team Services build. These tests run fine and pass locally, but timeout when I run them in VSTS. For each async test that connects to the database, I get

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
```

Here's my setup:

- graphql API using Apollo Server
- ArangoDB database insider a docker container

A typical test looks like this:

```
const database = require('../models')
...
describe('database setup', () => {
    it('sets up the database and it exists', () => {
        console.log(database.db)
        const collection=database.db.collection('agents')
        console.log(collection)
        return database.db.exists().then((result) => {
            expect(result).toBeTruthy()
        }).catch(err => {console.log(err)})
        .then(x => console.log(x)) 
    })
}
...
describe('help functions', () => {
    it('gets edge count for a node', async () => {
        let result = await database.getEdgeCount('nodes/1', 'inbound')
        expect(result).toBeGreaterThan(2)
    })
})
```

I'm running the tests in VSTS with an NPM task. The YAML for this task is basic:

```
steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: npm test
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: api
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'test --runInBand'
```

I know that the tests are connecting to the database because I can `console.log` the database object and get the database information.

Other things I've tried:

- Promise tests that don't hit the database, such as

  it('foo', async () => {
      await Promise.resolve()
      expect(1).toEqual(1)
    })
  These pass
- Increasing the timeout to 30000. This causes a couple of the tests with database calls to return `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this, and I think there were two issues going on:

1. The API was not actually connecting to the database. I was able to fix this by creating a new docker network and attaching both the database and VSTS build agent, [as described in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50016149/4879985)
2. The tests were starting before the database had completely started up. I added a `sleep` command in  a bash script before the tests which seemed to fix this.

Comment: Since your problem has been solved, you can mark the answer.