# What is the URL of my Docker service?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-mac

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
my_app:
  build: .
  net: host
  command: bin/server
  ports:
    - "3001:3001"
```

I start the service like this:

```
docker-compose up
```

And I can see that it is running:

```
my_app_1  | * Listening
```

But I can't figure out how to access it. None of these work:

```
localhost:3001
docker-machine:3001
127.0.0.1:3001
0.0.0.0:3001
```

How can I access my Docker service?

Comment: Check these out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157721/how-to-get-a-docker-containers-ip-address-from-the-host

Comment: @Adam Thanks, unfortunately the docs don't provide a solution. `docker ps` shows nothing in the `PORTS` column for my conainer. `docker ps <container_hash>` shows empty strings for all `IPAddress` values.

Comment: Did you try docker inspect?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's actually what I meant. `docker inspect <container_hash>` shows empty strings for all `IPAddress` values.

Comment: Could you post the `Dockerfile`, `bin/server` and `docker-compose.yml`? Redact anything sensitive and unnecessary. The ports appear fine (you could actually leave it as "3001" as "3001:3001" is redundant if you get what I'm saying). What version of docker-compose file are you using? My thought is that maybe you aren't mapping the correct port (bin/server is actually running on 5000 for example). The `net: host` is unnecessary if all of your containers are on the same network which essentially means they look like they are on the same machine.

Comment: Honestly I'd bet the issue is with the `docker-compose.yml` file. If you could just post that in it's entirety that would be great.

Comment: which OS are you running? also what is bin/server? Can you post the code for your server, Are you listening using `127.0.0.1` in server or `0.0.0.0`? It is important to listen on `0.0.0.0` in your `bin/server` program

Comment: ^ This is also true. Forgot about this but had that issue w/ a Flask app for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

docker inspect `container_name/hash` | grep Address