# How should I access an app started with: php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080

Tags: php, laravel, docker

The question is in the title, I am trying to dockerise a laravel app, and I start it with

```
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080
```

But then I try to access:

```
http://0.0.0.0:8080
```

but it doesn't work

How should I access it ???

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn' work, also tried 127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: `localhost` always refers to the current machine. If you use docker, you don't want to use `localhost`, but the IP or hostname of your dockerized machine

Comment: Woops, missed the docker tag

Comment: Have a look at https://www.codementor.io/patrickfohjnr/developing-laravel-applications-with-docker-4pwiwqmh4

Comment: I've read this article, but in my case, I don't want to use nginx. Also, I want to include all my dependencies into my image so it can be deployable.

Comment: @NicoHaase do you know how can I get that IP ?

Comment: maybe here ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157721/how-to-get-a-docker-containers-ip-address-from-the-host

Comment: Ok, I found my ip: 172.20.0.2, but now I get a timeout.... a bit better but still not working

Comment: How are you running docker and container?

Comment: @TarunLalwani, in Dockerfile, I use: CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080 and in I run docker-compose build, and docker-compose up

Comment: Can you also add the `docker-compose.yml` to the question?

Comment: done. minimalistic

Comment: I'd note that you should not use `php artisan serve` in production.

Comment: You have not mapped the ports? Add `ports: - "8080:8080"` to the compose file

Comment: @ceejayoz I will not, I will use it for local deployment :)

Comment: @TarunLalwani adding ports worked :) Please add it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is not working is that you have not mapped the ports

Add below to the service which is exposing the 8080 port.

```
ports:
  - "8080:8080"
```

For more details please refer to the below link

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/