# How to visit a docker service by ip address

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I'm new with `docker` and I'm probably missing a lot, although i went through the basic documentation and I'm trying to deploy a simple  **Spring Boot API**

I've deployed my **API** as a `docker-spring-boot` **.jar** file , then i installed `docker` and pushed it with the following commands:

- `sudo docker login`
- `sudo docker tag docker-spring-boot  phillalexakis/myfirstapi:01`
- `sudo docker push phillalexakis/myfirstapi:01`

Then i started the **API** with the docker `run` command:

`sudo docker run -p 7777:8085 phillalexakis/myfirstapi:01`

When i visit **localhost:7777/hello** I'm getting the desired **response**

This is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/docker-spring-boot.jar docker-spring-boot.jar
EXPOSE 8085
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","docker-spring-boot.jar"]
```

Based on this [answered post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157721/how-to-get-a-docker-containers-ip-address-from-the-host) this the command to get the `ip address`

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id
```

So, i run it with `container_name_or_id = phillalexakis/myfirstapi:01` and I'm getting this error

```
Template parsing error: template: :1:24: executing "" at <.NetworkSettings.Networks>: map has no entry for key "NetworkSettings"
```

If i manage somehow to get the `IP` will i be able to visit it and get the same **response**?

This is how i have it in my mind: **ip:7777/hello**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have used the *image* name and not the *container* name.
Get the container name by executing `docker ps`.
The container ID is the value in the first column, the container name is the value in the last column. You can use both.

Then, when you have the IP, you will be able to access your API at `IP:8085/hello`, not `IP:7777/hello`

The port 7777 is available on the Docker Host and maps to the port 8085 on the container. If you are accessing the container directly - which you do, when you use its IP address - you need to use the port that the container exposes.

---

There is also another alternative:
You can give the container a name when you start it by specifying the `--name` parameter:

```
sudo docker run -p 7777:8085 --name spring_api phillalexakis/myfirstapi:01
```

Now, from your Docker host, you can access your API by using that name: `spring_api:8085/hello`

Comment: okay so, i got the `IP` as you correctly pointed out. although i'm unable to connect at `IP:8085/hello`

Comment: @PhillAlexakis: Are you trying to connect from your Docker Host?

Comment: how can i find that out? i think i'm visiting it from the client side , my browser

Comment: That's not gonna work. The IP address of the container is only available from the Docker Host, i.e. from the machine that you executed `docker run` on. If you want make it available on the internet, you somehow need to route the traffic from the internet to the container. If the Docker host is available via the internet, one option is to use it's internet address and the port 7777 (don't forget to open it in the firewall).

Comment: oh alright, so i'm accessing it from the Docker host, I'm on the machine that i executed `docker run`

Comment: note that `sudo docker run -p 7777:8085 --name spring_api phillalexakis/myfirstapi:01` works the same with `sudo docker run -p 7777:8085 phillalexakis/myfirstapi:01`

Comment: about making it available over the internet, do you think this link might work? https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/ , is it just for internal IP's?

Comment: No, this won't work. Docker networks are for Docker internal organization purposes.

Answer (score 3):

You should never need to look up that IP address, and it often isn't useful.

If you're trying to call the service from outside Docker space, you've done the right thing: use the `docker run -p` option to publish its port to the host, and use the name of the host to access it.  If you're trying to call it from another container, [create a network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#manage-a-user-defined-bridge), make sure to run both containers with a `--net` option pointing at that network, and they can reach other using the other's `--name` as a hostname, and the container-internal port the other service is listening on (`-p` options have no effect and aren't required).

The Docker-internal IP address just doesn't work in a variety of common situations.  If you're on a different host, it will be unreachable.  If your local Docker setup uses a virtual machine (Docker Machine, Docker for Mac, minikube, ...) you can't reach the IP address directly from the host.  Even if it does work, when you delete and recreate the container, it's likely to change.  Looking it up as you note also requires an additional (privileged) operation, which the `docker run -p` path avoids.

---

The invocation you have [matches the `docker inspect` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/#get-an-instances-ip-address) (as @DanielHilgarth notes, make sure to run it on the *container* and not the *image*).  In the specific situation where it will work (you are on the same native-Linux host as the container) you will need to use the unmapped port, *e.g.* `http://172.17.0.2:8085/hello`.

Comment: correct, the returned `IP` from my container is `172.17.0.2` , so `http://172.17.0.2:8085/hello` works perfectly as  @DanielHilgarth noted also, thank you

Comment: if i push another version and restart the container is it still accessed at `172.17.0.2` ?

Comment: Not necessarily, no.

Comment: so i need to lookup the `IP` the same way i did right?

Comment: You need the `docker run -p` option, and to access the service via your host's DNS name or IP address (which is probably more stable) and the published port.