# Can't connect to Oracle 19.3 with 19.3 JDBC driver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

We have a project running with an Oracle 19.3 database, and a Java application using the Oracle 19.3 JDBC driver (which is available on Maven Central). On Windows with JRE 1.8, everything is fine, but when I run either on our build server or in WSL Ubuntu with OpenJDK 11.0.3 it refuses to connect to the database. Specifically:

```
ERROR: Unexpected error
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException:
Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<host>:<port>/<db>) for user '<user>': IO Error: Invalid argument, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 08006
Error Code : 17002
Message    : IO Error: Invalid argument, Authentication lapse 0 ms.

        at JuliasApplication.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:60)
        ...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Invalid argument, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:874)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:793)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:57)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:747)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:562)
        ...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid argument, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:870)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.sendOutOfBandData(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.sendOutOfBandData(SocketChannelImpl.java:521)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.sendUrgentData(SocketAdaptor.java:323)
        at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.sendUrgentByte(TcpNTAdapter.java:433)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:159)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:340)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1596)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:588)
        ... 12 more
```

If I switch in the 18.3 JDBC driver everything is fine in both environments; if I switch in an 18.3 database everything is fine in both environments. That does give us a workaround for now, but it feels very uncomfortable that we don't understand what's going on. And I can't find anything online about an "Authentication lapse". Can anyone see any clues which would explain the failure?

Comment: Are you using `ojdbc10` or `ojdbc8`?

Comment: Did you consider contacting Oracle for support? Also check if you're using other Oracle db related libraries (eg UCP, nls data, etc), and make sure they are all the same version.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `ojdbc8`

Comment: this still doesnt work. Is there any workaround without downgrading to ojdbc8`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the underlying Socket implementation is not allowing OOB.
As a workaround, you can disable the OOB check by setting the connection property CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_DISABLE_OUT_OF_BAND_BREAK to "true".
Please refer this link : https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_DISABLE_OUT_OF_BAND_BREAK

The link above no longer mentions the "out of band break" issue, so here's some alternatives:

- put `DISABLE_OOB=on` in your `sqlnet.ora` file, per [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#NETRF185).
- [for your java apps](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2366779/how-to-cancel-long-query) put `-Doracle.net.disableOob=true` on the command line
- [for apps like SQL Developer](https://thtechnology.com/2015/08/01/sql-developer-dropping-connections-solved/) you can add `AddVMOption -Doracle.net.disableOob=true` to your `sqldeveloper.conf`.

Comment: Excellent - that works! I assume it's a change in the driver implementation at v19.3, so we only need to set it if we see that driver version?

Comment: There is a fourth option that can be done to use the above solutions that @Aram mentioned. You can add "?oracle.net.disableOob=true" to the end of your JDBC Connection URL if neither of those options fit your needs. Example - jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname.com:1521/SCHEMA_NAME?oracle.net.disableOob=true

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with an **Oracle 19c docker container**, and after browsing half of the internet, I realized that the problem came from the fact that I used **localhost** as the Host, which for some reason is not supported by the 19.3.0.0+ Oracle driver.

After configuring the host with the IP address of the docker network interface (172.17.0.2 in my case), I could connect to Oracle server.

Hope this can help you as well.

Comment: Is that the IP address as returned by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157721/how-to-get-a-docker-containers-ip-address-from-the-host ? I get 172.18.0.2 but that returns `The Network Adapter could not establish the connection`

Comment: I use the address returned by the Unix command:
`ip -4 address show | grep docker0 | grep inet | awk '{print $2}' | sed -e 's@/.*@@g'`

Comment: I love you mate, I've spent three days on trying fixing this issue, and your answer finally helped me! PS. You can also check your container IP with command: `docker container inspect your-container-name` - it will print container settings, just find `IPAddress` key (or use `grep` for it).

Answer (score 0):

You must use ojdbc10.jar that is compliant with JDK10. Refer to the [FAQ (What are the Oracle JDBC releases Vs JDK versions?)](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html) for more details.

19.3    ojdbc10.jar with JDK10, JDK11 and ojdbc8.jar with JDK8, JDK9, JDK11
18.3    ojdbc8.jar with JDK8, JDK9, JDK10, JDK11

Comment: I looked at that page; I'm using OpenJDK11, it claims `ojdb8.jar` is OK with JDK11. (And note, no advice on higher JDKs)

Comment: If you are using JDK11 then, you can use ojdbc8.jar as it is compiled with JDK8 but can be used with JDK10 and JDK 11. FAQ will be updated with this information soon.