# How to get a IP addresses for all Docker containers from the host?

Tags: docker, networking

(Similar to [How to get a Docker container's IP address from the host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157721/how-to-get-a-docker-containers-ip-address-from-the-host), but slightly different since we are interested in *all* containers here)

I am running into an IP conflict with an internal server of ours which conflict with a Docker container. I have reconfigured `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, setting the `default-address-pools` setting to another network. But how do I now locate *which* of my seven Docker containers is happening to be using this particular IP network?

Comment: this will return all ips of running container. `docker inspect $(docker ps -q) | jq .[].NetworkSettings.IPAddress`

Comment: @Adiii Doesn't work for me, outputs a list of empty strings. Maybe dependent on what kind of networking you use?

Comment: if you are using host network container does not get IP adress.

Comment: @Adiii Sure, but even if you _don't_ use host networking the field you mention can be blank. This is the case for me where I typically run almost all Docker containers using `docker-compose`, with a dedicated network for each folder in which I have a `docker-compose.yml` file.

Answer (score 8):

This shows all container names and their IP addresses:

```
docker inspect $(docker ps -q ) \
--format='{{ printf "%-50s" .Name}} {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}} {{end}}'
```

Answer (score 4):

`docker network ls` helps you partially in this, by listing all Docker networks:

```sh
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                          DRIVER              SCOPE
3eb73575a250        bridge                        bridge              local
6ce0e4a8be79        centre_isp_services_default   bridge              local
abe7381d0bfd        elasticsearchhq_default       bridge              local
bb4387bdfac2        host                          host                local
cc3e69407994        metrics_default               bridge              local
55f1c6914497        none                          null                local
26f3247f27cc        postgres-112_default          bridge              local
```

`docker network inspect bridge` hints that the information is available under `IPAM.Config.Subnet`:

```
$ docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "3eb73575a2503d6758f8baed97ec478ebaed3e75df21b4269bd170edd94337de",
        "Created": "2019-11-08T11:33:49.489800945+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.31.0.0/24"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

One would have hoped that `docker network ls --format '{{.Name}} {{.IPAM.Config.Subnet}}'` would be able to give us this information, but regretfully, this is not the case. Only [a few fields](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_ls/#formatting) are available using that command.

### The solution

So, we have to jump through a few hoops to get it done. This does the trick:

```
$ for e in $(docker network ls --format '{{.Name}}') ; do docker network inspect $e --format '{{ printf "%-40s" .Name}} {{.IPAM.Config}}'; done
bridge                                   [{172.31.0.0/24   map[]}]
centre_isp_services_default              [{172.24.0.0/16  172.24.0.1 map[]}]
elasticsearchhq_default                  [{172.23.0.0/16  172.23.0.1 map[]}]
host                                     []
metrics_default                          [{172.22.0.0/16  172.22.0.1 map[]}]
none                                     []
postgres-112_default                     [{192.168.0.0/20  192.168.0.1 map[]}]
```

Comment: the first command  does job  :  docker network inspect bridge   .  The other command did not work.

Answer (score 1):

#### Get IP addresses, with network names, for multiple networks, for all containers

A container might have several IP addresses in several networks. To save time by minimizing guesswork and troubleshooting, this extended answer is provided.

Tested on Ubuntu, for containers created with `docker compose`.

Output format:

```
====================
/container-one-name

network-one-name
192.168.16.2

network-two-name
192.168.96.2

====================
/container-two-name

network-two-name
192.168.16.3

network-three-name
192.168.76.2
```

#### Query

For *running* containers:
`$(docker ps -q)`

For *all* containers (add `a`):
`$(docker ps -aq)`

`docker inspect -f '{{printf "====================\n"}}{{.Name}} {{range $net,$v := .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{printf "\n"}}{{printf "\n"}}{{printf "%s\n" $net}}{{.IPAddress}}{{printf "\n"}}{{end}}' $(docker ps -q)`

#### Result, real example

```
====================
/local-staging-proxy 

000-traefik-proxy-extrn
172.28.0.4


local-staging_fcgi-fpm
192.168.64.3

====================
/local-staging-web 

local-staging_db
192.168.32.3


local-staging_fcgi-fpm
192.168.64.2

====================
/local-staging-db 

local-staging_db
192.168.32.2

====================
/common-web-traefik 

000-traefik-proxy-extrn
172.28.0.2


010-traefik-and-socket-proxy-extrn
172.29.0.3

====================
/common-web-socket-proxy 

010-traefik-and-socket-proxy-extrn
172.29.0.2
```