# Why can't I connect to the flask server in docker container?

Tags: python, docker, flask, containers

My virtualmachine's os is CentOS 7 and its docker version is 19.03.8. I create my own image `python-image`. I run the following codes to create a new container:

```
docker run -it -p 5555:5000 python-image /bin/bash
```

In the container, a python script named `test.py` is as follows:

```
# test.py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def func():
    return "Hello docker!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Then I run `python test.py` and up the container.

In host shell, I run `curl http://127.0.0.1:5555/` and it prints:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I know that if specify `--network` as `host` when creating the container:

```
docker run -it --network host python-image /bin/bash
```

Starting the server and running `curl http://127.0.0.1:5555/` in host will get the expected information. I wonder what should I do when keep default value of `--network` to get the same result.

Comment: This mostly looks right, except that your `docker run` commands are starting a bash shell instead of your server application.  But the `-p` option, the `app.run()` call, and the port specifications all seem right.

Comment: ...is the container running inside a VM, and the browser outside the VM on the host?  You need to connect to the VM's IP address on the published port.

Comment: @DavidMaze Browser is inside the VM.

Answer (score 0):

When not specified, the default network used by Docker is the [Bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/networkingcontainers/). To access the container, you should use its own IP address. It's possible to [find the container's IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157721/how-to-get-a-docker-containers-ip-address-from-the-host) with:

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id
```

And then replace it by `127.0.0.1`.

Or you could save it in a variable and try:

```
$ container_ip=$(docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id)
$ curl http://${container_ip}:5555
```

Comment: This IP address doesn't work in a broad variety of common contexts (from MacOS or Windows hosts, if the browser isn't on the same physical host, if the container is running inside a VM).  There's not usually a reason to look up the container-private IP address; you should generally use a `docker run -p` published port to connect to it, as shown in the question.