# Docker Flask app behind nginx reverse-proxy sending 404

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

**Tl;DR:**
I have a running Flask application in a docker container. When I set up a nginx reverse proxy on the host machine in order to avoid having to enter the port number in the URL, the app send a 404 each time I hit the homepage at the defined nginx location. Why?

#### Context

I've got a prototype [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) app running as:

```sh
flask run --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000
```

It's [dockerized](https://www.docker.com/) and is exposed on port 8080 in a [compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) file:

```
ports:
  - "8080:5000"
```

Everything is working fine and when I hit the homepage at `http://my-server.org:8080`, the server happily says:

```
web_1  | in route /
web_1  | 166.24.119.203 - - [24/Sep/2041 10:29:20] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
web_1  | 166.24.119.203 - - [24/Sep/2041 10:29:21] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
web_1  | 166.24.119.203 - - [24/Sep/2041 10:29:21] "GET /static/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Now, in order to avoid having to enter the port in the URL, I've setup a simple MWE nginx reverse-proxy config file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` on the host machine (not yet dockerized for simplicity) and which is automatically [sym-linked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link) in `sites-enabled/`. This file contains the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name my-server.org;

    location /my-app {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

Please, note that [nginx](https://nginx.org/) is properly running:

```
# service nginx status
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-01-30 10:48:17 CET; 54min ago
   ...
```

Now, each time I hit the homepage at `http://my-server.org/my-app` now, the server returns:

```
web_1  | 172.27.0.1 - - [24/Sep/2041 12:34:26] "GET /my-app HTTP/1.0" 404 -
```

If that can help, I [noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20686101/6630397) that the IP shown here is actually the `Gateway` value of the `my-app_default` docker [network](https://docs.docker.com/network/) used by the service.

#### Question

How do I get my Flask app to properly work behind the nginx reverse-proxy?
I hope to understand enough from the answer(s) to be able to set up the same thing using [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That

```
    location /my-app {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
```

adds `/my-app` to `http://127.0.0.1:8080`.

Fix: Add a slash `/` after port:

```
    location /my-app/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    }
```

Yes, slash at end makes often a big difference in Nginx.

It is equivalent to:

```
    location /my-app/ {
        rewrite ^/my-app(.*)$ $1 last;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
```

IIRC, but I never use it.

BTW: Normally you put the symlink in `sites-enabled` not in `sites-available`.

Comment: I fixed the inversion of `sites-enabled` <-> `sites-available`, that was a mistake. I will test your solution and make all necessary updates after. Is the trailing slash in `/my-app/` also mandatory?

Comment: Sounds good, but I've noticed that the CSS and JS files (static folder) are not served...

Comment: Of course. Either you have to change the paths (see via keystroke F12 -> `Network` in the browser) or you have to rewrite the paths in your code with `sub_filter` or `subs_filter` on-the-fly.

Comment: This was really helpful

Comment: just wasted 2 hours debugging a back slash :(