# Debug Port in containerized WebLogic server

Tags: java, docker, containers, weblogic

I have a containerized WebLogic server which is running on my docker host mapped with three port: 5556, 6001, 7001. I have deployed my java product and everything is successful. I have also assaign a debug port on 8453 based on this article on WebLogic:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/java-cloud/jscug/enable-jvm-debug-port.html#GUID-C83E051D-3A28-4FE7-8333-20F40A06DAEA

In Intellij IDE, I configured my debug port on localhost port 8453 in ‘Edit Configuration…’ . here everything seems extremly OK and good. But as I am going to debug connection gets failed.

"unable to open debugger port (localhost:8453): java.net.connectException "Connection refused: connect"

I am a little bit naive in WebLogic server. It might be because somehow given port not mapped causes this error. Please help me if anybody there had such experience before.

Comment: you are trying to connect localhost:8453 which looks incorrect, as far as I know docker has its own IP, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/46310428/175554

Answer (score 1):

The environmental variable `JAVA_OPTIONS` is typically being set on `startWeblogic.sh`. With using a dockerized weblogic, the same variable needs to be set with the debug options and the address.

For example, you can set the variable on your `Dockerfile`.
The following will set the debug port for the Weblogic applications to  `4000` :

```
ENV JAVA_OPTIONS $JAVA_OPTIONS -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n
```

Also this port needs to be exposed.
For example on `docker-compose.yml`:

```
ports:
        - 4000:4000
```

On IntelliJ IDEA, the handshake is succesful without using IP Address of the container.

[image]