# How to connect to Docker SQL Server in GitHub Actions

Tags: sql-server, docker, .net-core, github-actions, nuke-build

I am trying to automate my testing using Nuke Build on GitHub. I am using a *Docker* to run a *SQL Server* container for testing. When it is run by GitHub Actions this error occurs. The image is successfully created and the error occurs when the tests try to access the database.

Error message:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot open database "MyDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
> Login failed for user 'sa'

It runs successfully locally on my *Windows 10* computer. I also tried to used Azure *DevOps Pipeline* and and the same error occurs. I tried looking around at similar issues such as [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/301) but they are not specific to when running on GitHub.

My .yaml script:

```
name: ci

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - feature/*
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - feature/*

jobs:
  ubuntu-latest:
    name: ubuntu-latest
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Run './build.cmd Test'
        run: ./build.cmd Test
```

Snippets from my Build.cs modeled from [this](https://github.com/josenerydev/TodoApp/blob/master/build/Build.cs):

```
Target RunDbContainer => _ => _
    .Before(Compile)
    .Executes(() =>
    {
        DockerTasks.DockerRun(x => x
            .SetImage("mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest")
            .SetEnv(new string[] { "ACCEPT_EULA=Y", "SA_PASSWORD=Password_01" })
            .SetPublish("1455:1433")
            .SetDetach(true)
            .SetName("sql1")
            .SetHostname("sql1"));
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    });

Target Test => _ => _
        .Triggers(UnitTest, RunDbContainer, IntegrationTest, SqlServerContainerStop);
```

The database is created and deleted during testing using *EF Core*.
A connection string is used to create a *DbContext*. Then *context.Database.EnsureCreated()* is used to create the database.

For the connection string I tired using *localhost* and the IP address gotten using:

```
"Server=127.17.0.2,1455;Database=MyDb;User Id=sa;Password=Password_01;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Trusted_Connection=False;"

"Server=localhost,1455;Database=MyDb;User Id=sa;Password=Password_01;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Trusted_Connection=False;"
```

I got the IP address following these [instuctions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157721/how-to-get-a-docker-containers-ip-address-from-the-host):

```
docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' sql1
```

Comment: Where are you setting up `MyDb` in the Docker container?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I don't have any explicit commands to create _MyDb_ using Docker. I add the _MyDb_ using EF Core with the connection string. I'm new to this so am not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: You won't be able to use `Database=MyDb` in your connection string until the database actually exists in the instance.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Are you able to direct me to some sources that can show me how to add the database?

Comment: The [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) page includes a link to [mssql-node-docker-demo-app](https://github.com/twright-msft/mssql-node-docker-demo-app) which shows you how to create a database, schema and data as part of your container's entrypoint. You only need to create the database, which will then allow EF Core to login using that database and continue with its initial migration.