# Debug a service defined in docker-compose.yml

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to enable remote debugging for one of the services included in my integration test. Most of the tests work fine, however if a test fails it is difficult to debug one of the other services. The (simplified) structure of the integration test is as follows:

Service A (service under test) -> GraphQL service -> Stubbed REST services

I'm using the following setup:

**Service A docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
  rest-stubs:
    image: rest-stubs:1.2.3
    container_name: rest-stubs
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"

  graphql-service:
    image: graphql-service:1.2.3
    container_name: graphql-service
    ports:
      - "8083:8080"
      - "5005:5005"
    environment:
      - some.stub-url=http://rest-stubs:8080/some-stub-url
```

**Dockerfile of graphql-service:**

```
FROM graphql-service

EXPOSE 8080 8080
EXPOSE 5005 5005

ADD app/target/service-*-exec.jar /app/spring-boot-service.jar

CMD ["-java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=*:5005,server=y,suspend=n \
            -jar /app/spring-boot-service.jar"]
```

When I perform the integration test located in service A, the services defined in the docker-compose.yml spin up. I would have expected to be able to connect to the graphQL service' remote debugging port on 5005, however I receive a `Unable to open debugger port (localhost:5005): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused (Connection refused)` exception.

Does anyone know how I can properly remote debug a docker service?

Comment: You must expose port 5005 in the docker-compose.yml

Comment: Thanks for your help, I originally had added the port but I guess I accidentally removed it while creating the snippet. I've updated my original post and added the 5005 port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer; I tried to connect to the container by using localhost:5005 settings in the IntelliJ remote debugger instead of the container's IP address.

I have obtained the IP address of the container using the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157721/how-to-get-a-docker-containers-ip-address-from-the-host) and used that IP address in Intellij's remote debugger dialog to connect instead.

Answer (score 1):

EXPOSE will only expose to others containers that are linked, such as other services in the network **without publishing the port to the host machine**.

You need to be publish it like this:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  rest-stubs:
    image: rest-stubs:1.2.3
    container_name: rest-stubs
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"

  graphql-service:
    image: graphql-service:1.2.3
    container_name: graphql-service
    ports:
      - "8083:8080"
      - "5005:5005"
    environment:
      - some.stub-url=http://rest-stubs:8080/some-stub-url
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I originally had added the port but I guess I accidentally removed it while creating the snippet. I've updated my original post and added the 5005 port.