# How can I access an NGINX web server running inside a Docker container on a virtual machine managed by Vagrant, from my Windows host machine?

Tags: linux, docker, vagrant, virtual-machine, vagrantfile

I have set up the Vagrantfile to use a public network with IP address 192.168.1.10 :

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :


Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "laravel/homestead"


  config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.1.10"

 
  
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.name = "Agent1"
  end
  config.vm.provision "docker" do |vb|

  end
  config.vm.hostname = "Agent1"
 
end
```

I have launched the Docker container with the command `docker run -it -p 88:80 nginx` to map port 80 inside the container to port 88 on the host machine. However, when I try to access the web server using URLs like 192.168.1.10:88, localhost:88, or 127.0.0.1:88 in my web browser, it doesn't work.

What could be causing this issue, and what URL should I use to access the NGINX web server from my Windows host machine?

Comment: Show the Dockerfile you're using and if it's a plain nginx image from Dockerhub, show where you have exposed port 88. Docker containers have their own network. You can find ip by doing `docker inspect`

Comment: I'm directly pulling nginx:latest from dockerhub without dockerfile ,i inspected the nginx container but i didn't get any informations about network

Comment: I still think it's a rabbit hole, but first google search result: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17157721/1294911

Comment: Windows can run Docker or Nginx on its own. Why do you need a VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not forwarded port 88 on the VM to your host.

First check you can SSH into that machine and `curl localhost:88`

Comment: Thank you, i've already fix this problem but your answer is the good when, i exposed the port and i fixed a machine host IP